# REST request for parking/fueling error: "The request is missing the app_id and app_code parameters."

Tags: rest, here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

When I am trying to make a request to parking or fuel location endpoints using an apiKey I generated on my HERE account, HERE gives me a **200 Status**, but it responds with the following:

> The request is missing the app_id and app_code parameters. They must both be passed as query parameters. If you do not have app_id and app_code, please obtain them through your customer representative or at http://developer.here.com/myapps.

The endpoints I'm testing are:

- https://parking-v2.cit.cc.api.here.com/parking/facilities.json
- https://fuel-v2.cit.cc.api.here.com/fuel/stations.json

An example request made would be:

```
https://fuel-v2.cit.cc.api.here.com/fuel/stations.json?apiKey=${APIKEY}&corridor=52.516667,13.383333;52.133333,11.616667;53.565278,10.001389&corridorWidth=10000
```

I'm trying to make the request using CURL and jsonp. Is there a way to generate an App Code for REST/Javascript requests? I know that there is the ability using iOS and Android, but I'm trying to display the information on a web app, not a mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.here.com/documentation/fuel-prices/dev_guide/topics/credentials.html

says you have to contact them to get app code etc.